# Access Data Source from AppleHealthKit API

Tags: ios, healthkit, wearables

I am reading sleep data from AppleHealthKit API, that have wearables connected.

Is it possible to retrieve:

1. If data came from wearable (e.g.--> True/False)
2. Wearable brand / Model (e.g. apple or Applewatch2)
3. Software Version (e.g. 1.3.4)

Are the specific permissions that need to be asked to retrieve source data?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the sourceRevision and device properties on the sleep sample. That may have the info you need. You don't need additional permissions to access this.

Comment: have you tried this yourself? when i extract device data i am seening a lot of NULL. (apple watch attached to apple healthkit)